# Thread-safety of Matrix class

Tags: java, thread-safety, matrix

Please criticize the `MatrixNotThreadSafe` class and other classes. How can I improve the design of the Matrix interface? How can I make the classes and tests clearer?

[Code on GitHub](https://github.com/Leonideveloper/Matrix/tree/master/Matrix/src/com/gmail/leonidandand/matrix)

**Position.java**

```
public class Position {
    public final int row;
    public final int column;

    public Position(int row, int column) {
        if (row < 0 || column < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if ((obj == null) || !(obj instanceof Position)) {
            return false;
        }
        Position other = (Position) obj;
        return (this.row == other.row) && (this.column == other.column);
    }
}
```

**TestPosition.java**

```
public class TestPosition {

    @Test
    public void testCreation() {
        Position pos = new Position(1, 2);
        assertEquals(1, pos.row);
        assertEquals(2, pos.column);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRowsIsZero() {
        new Position(0, 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testColumnsZero() {
        new Position(2, 0);
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testIllegalRows() {
        new Position(-1, 2);
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testIllegalColumns() {
        new Position(1, -2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals() {
        assertTrue(new Position(1, 2).equals(new Position(1, 2)));
        assertFalse(new Position(1, 2).equals(new Position(0, 0)));
        assertFalse(new Position(1, 2).equals(null));
    }
}
```

**Dimension.java**

```
public class Dimension {
    public final int rows;
    public final int columns;

    public Dimension(int rows, int columns) {
        if (rows <= 0 || columns <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Dimension constructor: rows and columns must be positive");
        }
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Dimension) {
            Dimension other = (Dimension) obj;
            return rows == other.rows && columns == other.columns;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return rows * columns;
    }
}
```

**TestDimension.java**

```
public class TestDimension {

    @Test
    public void testCreation() {
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(1, 2);
        assertEquals(1, dim.rows);
        assertEquals(2, dim.columns);
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRowsIsZero() {
        new Dimension(0, 1);
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRowsIsNegative() {
        new Dimension(-1, 1);
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testColumnsIsZero() {
        new Dimension(1, 0);
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testColumnsIsNegative() {
        new Dimension(1, -2);
    }

    public void testEquals() {
        assertTrue(new Dimension(33, 22).equals(new Dimension(33, 22)));
        assertFalse(new Dimension(1, 2).equals(new Dimension(3, 1)));
        assertFalse(new Dimension(2, 4).equals(null));
    }

    public void testHashCode_NotThrowsExceptions() {
        new Dimension(2, 3).hashCode();
    }
}
```

**Matrix.java**

```
public interface Matrix<T> {
    boolean contains(T elem);
    Dimension getDimension();
    int rows();
    int columns();
    T get(Position pos);
    T get(int row, int column);
    void set(Position pos, T value);
    void set(int row, int column, T value);
    void fill(T value);
    void forEach(OnEachHandler<T> onEachHandler);
    void swap(Position pos1, Position pos2);
}
```

**OnEachHandler.java**

```
public interface OnEachHandler<T> {
    void handle(Position pos, T elem);
}
```

**MatrixNotThreadSafe.java**

```
public class MatrixNotThreadSafe<T> implements Matrix<T> {
    private final int rows;
    private final int columns;
    private final T[][] values;

    public MatrixNotThreadSafe(Dimension dim) {
        this(dim.rows, dim.columns);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MatrixNotThreadSafe(int rows, int columns) {
        if (rows <= 0 || columns <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.values = (T[][]) new Object[rows][columns];
    }

    public MatrixNotThreadSafe(Matrix<T> other) {
        this(other.rows(), other.columns());
        other.forEach(new OnEachHandler<T>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Position pos, T elem) {
                set(pos, elem);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(T elem) {
        for (int row = 0; row < rows(); ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < columns(); ++column) {
                if (elementsAreEqual(elem, get(row, column))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean elementsAreEqual(Object e1, Object e2) {
        return (e1 == e2) ||
               ((e1 != null) && (e1.equals(e2))) ||
               ((e2 != null) && (e2.equals(e1)));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getDimension() {
        return new Dimension(rows(), columns());
    }

    @Override
    public int rows() {
        return rows;
    }

    @Override
    public int columns() {
        return columns;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(Position pos) {
        return get(pos.row, pos.column);
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int row, int column) {
        checkIndexes(row, column);
        return values[row][column];
    }

    private void checkIndexes(int row, int column) {
        if (row < 0 || column < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(stringByRowColumn(row, column));
        }
        if (row >= rows() || column >= columns()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(stringByRowColumn(row, column));
        }
    }

    private String stringByRowColumn(int row, int column) {
        return "[" + row + ", " + column + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public void set(Position pos, T value) {
        set(pos.row, pos.column, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int row, int column, T value) {
        checkIndexes(row, column);
        values[row][column] = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void fill(final T value) {
        forEach(new OnEachHandler<T>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Position pos, T elem) {
                set(pos, value);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(OnEachHandler<T> onEachHandler) {
        for (int row = 0; row < rows(); ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < columns(); ++column) {
                Position pos = new Position(row, column);
                T elem = get(row, column);
                onEachHandler.handle(pos, elem);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void swap(Position pos1, Position pos2) {
        T temp = get(pos1);
        set(pos1, get(pos2));
        set(pos2, temp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if ((obj == null) || !(obj instanceof Matrix<?>)) {
            return false;
        }
        Matrix<?> other = (Matrix<?>) obj;
        if (this.rows() != other.rows() || this.columns() != other.columns()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < rows(); ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < columns(); ++column) {
                if (!elementsAreEqual(get(row, column), other.get(row, column))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int totalHashCode = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < rows(); ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < columns(); ++column) {
                totalHashCode += hashCodeOfElement(row, column);
            }
        }
        return totalHashCode * (rows() + columns());
    }

    private int hashCodeOfElement(int row, int column) {
        T element = get(row, column);
        return element != null ? element.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

**TestMatrixNotThreadSafe.java**

```
public class TestMatrixNotThreadSafe {
    private static final Integer VALUE = 5;
    private static final int ROWS = 10;
    private static final int COLUMNS = 20;

    private Matrix<Integer> matrix;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.matrix = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Integer>(ROWS, COLUMNS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMatrixCopyConstructor() {
        fillMatrix(matrix);
        Matrix<Integer> copy = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Integer>(matrix);
        assertEquals(matrix.rows(), copy.rows());
        assertEquals(matrix.columns(), copy.columns());
        for (int row = 0; row < copy.rows(); ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < copy.columns(); ++column) {
                assertEquals(matrix.get(row, column), copy.get(row, column));
            }
        }
    }

    private void fillMatrix(final Matrix<Integer> matrixToFill) {
        for (int row = 0; row < matrixToFill.rows(); ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < matrixToFill.columns(); ++column) {
                matrixToFill.set(row, column, elementForPosition(row, column));
            }
        }
    }

    private Integer elementForPosition(int row, int column) {
        return row * column;
    }

    @Test
    public void testInitValueIsNull() {
        assertNull(matrix.get(0, 0));
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testConstructorNegativeDimension() {
        new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Integer>(1, -1);
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testConstructorDimensionIsZero() {
        new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Integer>(0, 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testContains() {
        assertFalse(matrix.contains(2));
        matrix.set(new Position(0, 0), 2);
        assertTrue(matrix.contains(2));
        matrix.set(new Position(0, 0), 1);
        assertFalse(matrix.contains(2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testJustCreatedMatrixContainsNull() {
        assertTrue(matrix.contains(null));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetDimension() {
        assertEquals(new Dimension(ROWS, COLUMNS), matrix.getDimension());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDimensionOfMatrix() {
        assertEquals(ROWS, matrix.rows());
        assertEquals(COLUMNS, matrix.columns());
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testGetByNegativePosition() {
        matrix.get(1, -1);
    }

    @Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testGetByOutOfBoundsPosition() {
        matrix.get(ROWS + 1, 0);
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testSetByNegativePosition() {
        matrix.set(-1, 0, VALUE);
    }

    @Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testSetByOutOfBoundsPosition() {
        matrix.set(0, COLUMNS + 1, VALUE);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetSet() {
        fillMatrix(matrix);
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < COLUMNS; ++column) {
                assertEquals(elementForPosition(row, column), matrix.get(row, column));
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testFill() {
        final Integer one = 1;
        matrix.fill(one);
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < COLUMNS; ++column) {
                assertTrue(one.equals(matrix.get(row, column)));
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testFillByNullValues() {
        matrix.fill(null);
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < COLUMNS; ++column) {
                assertNull(matrix.get(row, column));
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSwap() {
        Matrix<Integer> matrix = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Integer>(2, 2);
        Position pos1 = new Position(0, 0);
        Position pos2 = new Position(1, 1);
        Integer val1 = 1;
        Integer val2 = 2;
        matrix.set(pos1, val2);
        matrix.set(pos2, val1);
        matrix.swap(pos1, pos2);
        assertEquals(val2, matrix.get(pos2));
        assertEquals(val1, matrix.get(pos1));
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testSwapIllegalArguments() {
        Position pos1 = new Position(0, 0);
        Position pos2 = new Position(0, -1);
        matrix.swap(pos1, pos2);
    }

    @Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testSwapPositionOutOfBounds() {
        Position pos1 = new Position(0, COLUMNS + 1);
        Position pos2 = new Position(0, 0);
        matrix.swap(pos1, pos2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testForEach_AllElementsAreProcessedExactlyOnce() {
        final Matrix<Boolean> flags = getMatrixInitializedByFalse(ROWS, COLUMNS);
        flags.forEach(new OnEachHandler<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Position pos, Boolean elem) {
                assertFalse(flags.get(pos));
                assertFalse(elem);
                flags.set(pos, true);
            }
        });
        for (int row = 0; row < flags.rows(); ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < flags.columns(); ++column) {
                assertTrue(flags.get(row, column));
            }
        }
    }

    private Matrix<Boolean> getMatrixInitializedByFalse(int rows, int columns) {
        final Matrix<Boolean> flags = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Boolean>(rows, columns);
        for (int row = 0; row < flags.rows(); ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < flags.columns(); ++column) {
                flags.set(row, column, false);
            }
        }
        return flags;
    }

    @Test
    public void testForEach_Order_LeftToRight_UpToDown() {
        final Matrix<Boolean> flags = getMatrixInitializedByFalse(ROWS, COLUMNS);
        flags.forEach(new OnEachHandler<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Position pos, Boolean elem) {
                if (!pos.equals(new Position(0, 0))) {
                    assertPreviousElementWasProcessed(flags, pos);
                }
                flags.set(pos, true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void assertPreviousElementWasProcessed(Matrix<Boolean> matrix, Position pos) {
        Position positionBefore = positionBefore(matrix.rows(), matrix.columns(), pos);
        assertTrue(matrix.get(positionBefore));
    }

    private Position positionBefore(int rows, int columns, Position pos) {
        if (pos.column - 1 < 0) {
            return new Position(pos.row - 1, columns - 1);
        } else {
            return new Position(pos.row, pos.column - 1);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals() {
        Matrix<Integer> matrix1 = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Integer>(1, 2);
        matrix1.set(0, 0, VALUE);
        matrix1.set(0, 1, VALUE);
        Matrix<Integer> matrix2 = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Integer>(1, 2);
        matrix2.set(0, 0, VALUE);
        matrix2.set(0, 1, VALUE);
        assertTrue(matrix1.equals(matrix2));
        matrix2.set(0, 0, VALUE + 1);
        assertFalse(matrix1.equals(matrix2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_WithNull() {
        assertFalse(matrix.equals(null));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_DifferentClass() {
        assertFalse(matrix.equals(Integer.valueOf(1)));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_NullElements_DifferentTemplateParameters() {
        Matrix<Integer> integerMatrix = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Integer>(2, 2);
        Matrix<Boolean> booleanMatrix = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Boolean>(2, 2);
        assertTrue(integerMatrix.equals(booleanMatrix));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_NotNullElements_DifferentTemplateParameters() {
        Matrix<Integer> integerMatrix = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Integer>(1, 1);
        Matrix<Boolean> booleanMatrix = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Boolean>(1, 1);
        integerMatrix.set(0, 0, Integer.valueOf(0));
        booleanMatrix.set(0, 0, Boolean.valueOf(false));
        assertFalse(integerMatrix.equals(booleanMatrix));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_NullElements_SameTemplateParameters() {
        assertEquals(matrix, new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Integer>(ROWS, COLUMNS));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_DifferentDimensions_NullElements() {
        Matrix<Integer> matrix1 = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Integer>(2, 2);
        Matrix<Integer> matrix2 = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Integer>(2, 1);
        assertFalse(matrix1.equals(matrix2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_NotNullElements_With_NullElements() {        
        Matrix<Boolean> falseElements = getMatrixInitializedByFalse(ROWS, COLUMNS);
        Matrix<Boolean> nullElements = new MatrixNotThreadSafe<Boolean>(ROWS, COLUMNS);
        assertFalse(falseElements.equals(nullElements));
    }

    @Test
    public void testHashCode_NotThrowsExceptions() {
        matrix.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: My biggest issue is that it does not do anything useful yet. The proof is in the pudding. You cannot add or multiply two of them. You cannot invert one. I know some people advocate test-driven development, which is cool, but if your code does not do anything, then it is by definition useless. Once you continue implementing your class, consider how stable your inversion operation is. It can be a big deal, this is why real matrix libraries can be messy.

Comment: Is not it better to place "useful" operations with the matrix in separate classes?  (Sorry for my bad English. Maybe I understood you incorrectly.)

Comment: Well, your architecture is already leading to a slow implementation. Usually the consumers of the matrix libraries expect it to run very fast. With your approach you may end up with jumping across different memory pages while performing any Matrix operation. I really do think that some sort of array could be better, given that your matrix can be represented by a 2D array easily. Most real matrix libs try to use hardware and graphics card to get stuff done fast. Anyhow, suppose you are not constrained by speed. Still, it helps to know what the consumers of the matrix class want.

Comment: Continued. You might want to make matrices immutable - makes code simpler to debug, is bad for performance. I would not delegate work to an outside handler; that would smell like http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AbuseOfUtilityClasses Also, if you look at what a matrix multiplication or inversion, etc. involves, you have to look at the entire matrix, cannot really work with just one cell at a time. So, I strongly believe that inside of the Matrix class is the best place to perform matrix operations. Doing so would keep things simple and keep the scope local. I think you started polishing smth unfinished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Position**

- While it implements `equals()` it doesn't implement `hashCode()`. It should.
- The `equals()` method could start with a test : `if (this == obj) { return true; }` While this isn't strictly necessary it can avoid a more costly `instanceof` check.
- I would advise to make this class `final`, and if not, then its `equals()` and `hashCode()` method, so subclasses cannot violate [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).
- You can probably get away with allowing direct field access here, but getter/setter would be better encapsulation.

**Dimension**

- Some of the remarks for `Position` apply to `Dimension` as well.
- `hashCode()` can be improved so that `new Dimension(4, 5)` does not map to the same hash as `new Dimension(5, 4)`

**Matrix**

- minimize the interface by getting rid of the convenience methods that take `int` params for `row` and `column`. They make the interface harder to maintain, and harder to understand.Same for the `rows()` and `columns()` method. Convenience methods seem so great, but they have to be kept in sync with the actual methods when implementations change. People looking at the interface must look at documentation to see if the methods really do the same, or not. It also makes things harder to test.

**MatrixNotThreadSafe**

- if you switch to a single dimension array to represent Matrix content, all the double loops be gone, improving cyclomatic complexity.
- I would use a `Dimension` field instead of the rows and columns fields. Both `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations will benefit.
- I would suggest renaming this to `ArrayMatrix`. A thread safe implementation can be named `ConcurrentMatrix` (analogous with Collections from JDK)

**Tests**

- Strive to have one assert per test :

so change

```
 @Test
 public void testEquals() {
     assertTrue(new Position(1, 2).equals(new Position(1, 2)));
     assertFalse(new Position(1, 2).equals(new Position(0, 0)));
     assertFalse(new Position(1, 2).equals(null));
 }
```

into :

```
@Test
public void testEqualsIdentityTrue() {
    Position position = new Position(1, 2);
    assertTrue(position.equals(position));
}

@Test
public void testValueEqualsTrue() {
    assertTrue(new Position(1, 2).equals(new Position(1, 2)));
}

@Test
public void testValueEqualsFalseIfColumnDiffers() {
    assertFalse(new Position(1, 2).equals(new Position(1, 3)));
}

@Test
public void testValueEqualsFalseIfRowDiffers() {
    assertFalse(new Position(1, 2).equals(new Position(3, 2)));
}
@Test
public void testEqualsFalseForNull() {
    assertFalse(new Position(1, 2).equals(null));
}
```

(ok, I added a few too)

You can also test whether hashCode() is in sync with equals().